# Copy Cells from 2 or more workbooks to a new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write some code which copies cells `C24, C25` and `D24, D25` from all the .xls files from location `"C:\MyPath\"` and I'm new to using `VBA` but I was looking for some solution online and was able to make up some code which combines all excel files in a folder and copies it to single workbook with each workbook going into each sheet.

Th code I worked on is

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyWorksheets()

  Const sPath = "C:\MyPath\"
  Dim sFile As String
  Dim wbkSource As Workbook
  Dim wSource As Worksheet
  Dim wbkTarget As Workbook

  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set wbkTarget = ActiveWorkbook
  sFile = Dir(sPath & "*.xls*")
  Do While Not sFile = ""
    Set wbkSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sPath & sFile, AddToMRU:=False)
    For Each wSource In wbkSource.Worksheets
      With wbkTarget
        wSource.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
      End With
    Next
    wbkSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
    sFile = Dir
  Loop

ExitHandler:
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
  Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

**May I know the changes or additions to the above code to get my solution?**

Comment: You say you want to copy C24, C25 and D24, D25 from all the .xls files in location "C:\MyPath\".  I assume copy them to `wbkTarget` but where in `wbkTarget`?  For example, you could copy them down columns C, D, E and F of a single worksheet with columns A and B reserved for the names of the source workbooks and worksheets.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that I want each file's C24, C25 and D24, D25 in as many sheets in wbkTarget with their respective names

Comment: Do I understand correctly? If there are 20 files in "C:\MyPath\" each with three worksheets, you want 60 worksheets created in the active workbook. Each of those 60 worksheets are to be empty except for C24:D25.  Are you sure? This seems very wasteful of space.  With the old version of Excel I use, adding an empty worksheet adds 2,048 bytes to a workbook's size.  Experiment with your version of Excel. You want the new worksheets to have names that match the source worksheets.  Do all the source worksheets have unique names?

Comment: You are right. Maybe I should go on as you said in first comment. I will go with a single worksheet with Columns A and B reserved for the names of the source workbooks and worksheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code to a new workbook.  I renamed worksheet Sheet1 as C24D25 and created a header row:

```
        A        B         C      D      E      F
  1 Workbook  Worksheet  C24    D24    C25    D25
```

At the top of your routine I added the extra variables and constants I required:

```
Const colTgtWbk As Long = 1
Const colTgtWsht As Long = 2
Const colTgtC24 As Long = 3
Const colTgtC25 As Long = 5

Dim wshtTarget As Worksheet
Dim rowTgtCrnt As Long

Set wshtTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("C24D25")
rowTgtCrnt = 2
```

Replace “C24D25” with your name for the worksheet into which values are collected.

I amended the definition of `sPath` to a folder on my laptop containing several workbooks.

Near the top of your code I commented out:

```
'On Error GoTo ErrHandler
```

and near the end I commented out:

```
'ExitHandler:
  'Exit Sub
'ErrHandler:
  'MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
  'Resume ExitHandler
```

I never include my own error handler during development and I never include one in a production macro unless I have discovered a need during development.  An error handler routine is not the best method for handling errors you expect and can test for.  They should be reserved for errors you cannot test for such as attempting to open a file for which you may not have read permission.

Around your main block:

```
  Set wbkSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sPath & sFile, AddToMRU:=False)
     to
   wbkSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

I added an If:

```
 If sFile <> wbkTarget.Name Then

 End If
```

This avoids attempting to reopen the workbook in which you are collecting data.

I deleted:

```
With wbkTarget
  wSource.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
 End With
```

and replaced this code with:

```
With wshtTarget
  .Cells(rowTgtCrnt, colTgtWbk).Value = wbkSource.Name
  .Cells(rowTgtCrnt, colTgtWsht).Value = wSource.Name
  wSource.Range("C24:D24").Copy Destination:=.Cells(rowTgtCrnt, colTgtC24)
  wSource.Range("C25:D25").Copy Destination:=.Cells(rowTgtCrnt, colTgtC25)
  rowTgtCrnt = rowTgtCrnt + 1
End With
```

This is the code that builds the rows in worksheet C24D25.

At the bottom I added:

```
wshtTarget.Columns.AutoFit
```

This expands the columns to the width of the data found.

The result of the changes above is:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyWorksheets()

  Const colTgtWbk As Long = 1
  Const colTgtWsht As Long = 2
  Const colTgtC24 As Long = 3
  Const colTgtC25 As Long = 5

  Dim wshtTarget As Worksheet
  Dim rowTgtCrnt As Long

  Set wshtTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("C24D25")
  rowTgtCrnt = 2

  Const sPath = "C:\DataArea\SOTest\Excel\"
  Dim sFile As String
  Dim wbkSource As Workbook
  Dim wSource As Worksheet
  Dim wbkTarget As Workbook

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set wbkTarget = ActiveWorkbook
  sFile = Dir(sPath & "*.xls*")
  Do While sFile <> ""

   If sFile <> wbkTarget.Name Then

      Set wbkSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sPath & sFile, AddToMRU:=False)
      For Each wSource In wbkSource.Worksheets

        With wshtTarget
          .Cells(rowTgtCrnt, colTgtWbk).Value = wbkSource.Name
          .Cells(rowTgtCrnt, colTgtWsht).Value = wSource.Name
          wSource.Range("C24:D24").Copy Destination:=.Cells(rowTgtCrnt, colTgtC24)
          wSource.Range("C25:D25").Copy Destination:=.Cells(rowTgtCrnt, colTgtC25)
          rowTgtCrnt = rowTgtCrnt + 1
        End With

      Next
      wbkSource.Close SaveChanges:=False

   End If

    sFile = Dir
  Loop

  wshtTarget.Columns.AutoFit

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I hope the purposes of the changes I have made are obvious,  Ask questions if necessary.

Comment: might seems silly but I have issues connection `If and End If` and I get an error `End If without block If` but works fine if I remove `If` block

Comment: I have added the complete code at the bottom of my answer.  Perhaps this will allow you to see what is going wrong.

Comment: I was was testing through this. this code breaks after processing few files and closes the workbook.

Comment: I tested it with a folder containing dozens of workbooks.  You will have be more specific if I am to offer any pointers..  Is there anything special about the last workbook processed?  Were all worksheets in the last workbook recorded?  Do you mean the active workbook was closed?

Comment: YEs, I tried with around 200 workbooks and it broke and closed the active workbook

Comment: The `If sFile <> wbkTarget.Name Then` ... `End If` should stop anything happening with the active workbook.  Have you included that `If` statement.  VBA should stop and warn you if you try to reopen a workbook.  Have you retained your own error handling routine.

Comment: No I didn't retain my code and I was just using the code in the final answer. Anyways I will debug it

Comment: @Dev.  Any success at debugging?  I have been unable to get the effects you describe with my code.

Comment: Yeah I think so. It is just that I have some corrupted files in the folder. I handled that exception

Comment: @Dev I pleased you are having some success.  I have encountered problems with VBA opening almost any rubbish as workbooks.